# How to update and merge the data of a nested document in MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I've just started learning Back-End development. And I'm building a demo app. I have a collection with document looking like so:

```
{
  "_id":"6083801e4b59bb38eeb9f232",
  "sets":4,
  "reps":"4-6",
  "name":"deadlift",
  "description":null,
  "instructions":[
    "keep feet sholder width apart",
    "use legs first and then move to lower back"
  ]
}
```

Now, I'm making an API to update the document like this:

```js
db.collection('exercises').updateOne({ _id }, { $set: update })
```

where _id is the id value, and `update` is a JS object with updated values that looks like this:

```
{
  "_id":"608380294b59bb38eeb9f233",
  "description":[
    "Second day - Legs 2"
  ],
  "instructions":[
    "More reps, less weight",
    "keep feet shoulder-width apart",
    "use legs first and then move to lower back",
    "Keep at least 2 reps in the tank"
  ],
  "reps":"6-8",
  "sets":4,
  "addNew":true
}
```

I want to merge the existing exercise data with the updated one. But my query doesn't work. One way could be to `get` the exercise data by id and then merge it manually. And then send the new data as an update. But I was wondering if there is a graceful way to handle this issue. As in my solution, I will have to make 2 network calls and I don't think it is a nice way to solve this issue. Keep in mind that `update` can be any field, it can be just one field, it can be multiple fields. It can be a nested object as well.

Comment: but you can simply update https://mongoplayground.net/p/qWG2SrJGwi6

Comment: @varman does that mean I need to pass an object named `update` to `$set`? As the line number in your example shows you are passing the `update` object? How do I merge the existing values to the object? Do I need to fetch the existing document, merge and then make the update query? I'm sorry if that's an obvious question, but I am little new to Mongo.

Comment: You can update to root document also, but both has different `_id`, so u need to be careful when overriding existing fields https://mongoplayground.net/p/eT6i7yECRTV

Comment: no, I don't need to update the ID field, I just copied the request payload from the postman. ID always remains the same. but the rest of the fields will/can be updated. I am sending ID from the payload as this way I would know which document in the collection I need to update.

FE will send only the updated part. BE will take care of merging the existing data and the new data.

Comment: hope this solves your problem

Comment: @varman question is how do I merge the data? I see that you are passing all the data(old and new) in the demo. So I am asking do I need to fetch the data first, then merge it and make the update call? Or is there a better way(some mongo command) to merge the data at mongo end?

Comment: how do you know that particular object for the particular document? is the update object you showed in collection?

Comment: @varman all the values in the `update` object are already present in the exercise collection's document.

Comment: So basically you have two collections which have multiple documents, how do you find and update the object to first collection you posted